# zend framework global functions

Tags: zend-framework

Ok I know this is all sorts of Wrong.. But..

I have a few functions I use regularly, and I want to make them more easily 
accessible to me.

Right now I'm wrapping them in a Model_class as a work around, and I couldn't
figure out what to do with them.

Where does someone put these common functions.

I'm sure others have third-party libraries which they must use, and I'm not 
sure where to put them.

-Patrick.

Comment: There are several approaches you can take for this in ZF, depending on the purpose of your code. Please explain what your functions do so we can better suggest where to put them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put it in a file called functions.php and include that file in your bootstrap (index.php) file. Then you can access your precious functions everywhere.

Comment: That is a simple solution.

Do I use a "require_once" to load the functions.php file ?

Thx

Comment: Ah.. Got it.. I just needed to use the require_once setting.

THx